# Down sampling in the frequency domain

Tags: frequency, ifft

I would like to down sample a signal from it's original sampling rate of 2,000,000 samples per second to 48,000 (or 44100) starting from the output of an FFT.  This FFT delivers 16384 data points (8192 real and 8192 imaginary).  The data comes from a software defined radio as I and Q data.
I cannot do this in the time domain as I do not have the tools in my app to do so.  So I need to start from the FFT, drop the necessary data, then perform an iFFT.  These tools I have.
What I need help with, is determining how many samples to drop and how to arrange the data afterwards to be delivered to an inverse FFT which needs real and imaginary data.  I understand that you just drop the upper frequencies.  But then what?
Can someone help out please?
Thanks

Comment: You might search for "Turning Overlap-Save into a Multiband
Mixing, Downsampling Filter Bank" by Borgerding. It describes a method for implementing a downsampling filter (with optional frequency shifting) efficiently in the frequency domain.